# While loop not executing right if conditions even if they are true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time, while-loop, conditional-statements

My variable `normalWeek` is equal to a certain time period, if this time period is true then the first condition will be executed if it is not the while loop will execute the second condition until the variable `normalWeek` becomes true. But the problem is that when I execute the code the first condition that the loop finds to be true will be the only one executed even after another condition becomes true.

For example, variable `normalWeek` is true if it is 6 am, but the loop will continue to execute this same condition even after it is not 6 am, it basically ignores the other condition.

```js
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDay();
var minute = date.getMinutes();


function goodSignal() {
    console.log(b, 'Good Signal');
}
function badSignal() {
    console.log(b, 'Bad Signal');
}
function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
 
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
    }
}

let b = 0;

let normalWeek = (hour === 6 || hour === 10) && (day > 0 && day < 6);

while (b === 0) {
    console.log('Testing Started...');

    while (normalWeek === true) {
        b++;
        goodSignal();
        sleep(10000);
        continue;
    }
    
    while (normalWeek === false) {
        b++;
        badSignal();
        sleep(10000);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand th eproblem correctly, you need to call getHours and getDay in th eloop to check if it's after 6:00 AM.

Comment: Agree with arp5. The hour and day variables aren't getting updated. Also, does the while loop even loop? On true or false, b gets incremented, which will break the loop. Is that just for testing?

Comment: The actual problem is that after one of the if conditions is true the loop will always choose this same condition to be executed even after said condition becomes false. For example. normalWeek variable is only true if it is 9am(i know that normalWeek variable has a different value in my code, just using 9am to be easier to explain), if time passes and now is 10am so normalWeek is false, but normal week continues to be executed as if it is true when it was supposed to be false, and execute the other condition.

Comment: I just changed if using while, but it keeps having the same issue

Comment: Now that you have created inner `while` loops, your `continue` statements will just repeat the inner loops endlessly. Ignoring the code you've written for a moment, what do you want your program to ultimately do?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Iago: Take a look at the code below: I included explanations in comments. It illustrates how you can check for a "normal week" using a new date each time instead of reusing the same date. I did my best to interpret your question's objective, but if you want to clarify something, just let me know in a comment and I'll check it out.

```js
// This will compute a new date every time instead of using the same date each time
function isNormalWeek () {
  const date = new Date();
  const day = date.getDay();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  // return (hours === 6 || hours === 10) && (day > 0 && day < 6);

  // Just for this example, let's say it's normal if the seconds are even
  // instead of waiting for 06:00-06:59 or 10:00-10:59 on a weekday
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  return seconds % 2 === 0; // seconds are even
}

// This is preferable to running a loop endlessly for no reason
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main () {
  function goodSignal () {
    console.log(b, 'Good Signal');
  }
  
  function badSignal () {
    console.log(b, 'Bad Signal');
  }

  let b = 0;

  // Always true, loop forever
  while (true) {
    b += 1;

    // Invoke one function if the week is "normal", otherwise invoke the other
    isNormalWeek()
      ? goodSignal()
      : badSignal();

    // await sleep(10_000);

    // Just for this example, let's run the loop again after waiting one second
    // instead of waiting ten seconds
    await sleep(1_000);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you, i have an additional question, i need to run this code 24/7, but i cant do this in my computer, is it possible to use a server?

Comment: Yes, you can run it on a server using a JavaScript runtime like [Deno](https://deno.land/) or [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/). However, that's a different question, so you might want to search for that on StackOverflow or ask a new one.